# how to get the last modified file, so that can be used as arguments in other commands?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

how to get the last modified file . so that can use it as a argument in other commands 
i tried

`unzip ls -ltr | tail -1`

but this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware, parsing the output of `ls` might fail, read e.g. [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) or [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/33390).

As you have the `zsh`tag in your question, here is a *zsh* specific solution:

First, put all entries (`*`) in the current directory into an array `files`, ordered (`o`) by modification time (`m`):

```
files=(*(om))
```

As `*` is a so-called *globbing pattern*, `(om)` are called *Glob Qualifiers*, which have an own section in `man zshexpn` with that title.

Now, you can use the first element of that array to reference the newest file

```
echo $files[1]
```

Read `man zshparam` for more info about arrays.

Comment: thank you . this solved my issue also could you share where from where to find this zsh specific shortcuts

Comment: @PrinzPiuz: Yes, sorry, you are right -- I should have referenced the documentation. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i found this

`last_file=$(ls -lrt | tail -1)`
`name=$(cut -d' ' -f10 <<< $last_file)`
`echo $name`

Comment: Hi, welcome to Super User! Where did you find this? Can you explain it?

Comment: i myself tried and it worked (in my case )

Comment: Sorry for being unclear- can you [edit] your answer explain where you found the command you are using, and explain what each part does? This will help others who read your question and answer :)

Comment: its not an effective solution each time we need to change feild value below answer solved my issue